VirtualStringTree component doesn't allow the user to focus nodes except for those in the first column
I'm working with Delphi 11 (Alexandria).
In the project I'm currently working on I'm showing a grid with a TVirtualStringTree (the component is from the library VirtualTree for VCL 2024.02, by TurboPack).

The problem is that, it doesn't matter where I click, the only cells that can be focussed are those in the first column, while I want to be able to focus any cell by cliccking on it.
Does anyone have an idea of what may be the cause?
I've tryed changing the paramenters of the component, and looking for people with a similar issue, but nothing seems to be of help.
